# How can I initialize these structs with field names?

Tags: c++, initialization

I was wondering if I could initialize the following structs in the way I've indicated:

```
struct Attribute
{
    int location;
    int binding;
    int offset;
    int format;
};

namespace VertexInputLayouts
{
    struct GUI
    {
        static inline char numAttributes = 3;
        
        static inline Attribute attributes[3] =
        {
            {0, 0, 0, 0},
            {1, 1, 1, 1},
            {2, 2, 2, 2}
        };
        
        // I would prefer it like this...
        /*attribute[0].location = 0;
        attribute[0].binding = 0;
        attribute[0].offset = 0;
        attribute[0].format = 0;

        attribute[1].location = 1;
        attribute[1].binding = 0;
        attribute[1].offset = 0;
        attribute[1].format = 0;*/
}
```

Comment: Use C++20 and aggregate initialization
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization
look at : Designated initializers.


Otherwise you probably have to stick to what you're doing. Or indeed spelling it out like you do at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it through the constructor and call it by creating a dummy global scope object:

```cpp
// ...

namespace VertexInputLayouts
{
    struct GUI
    {
        static inline char numAttributes = 3;
        
        static inline Attribute attribute[3];
        
        constexpr GUI() {
            // I would prefer it like this...
            attribute[0].location = 0;
            attribute[0].binding = 0;
            attribute[0].offset = 0;
            attribute[0].format = 0;

            attribute[1].location = 1;
            attribute[1].binding = 0;
            attribute[1].offset = 0;
            attribute[1].format = 0;

            // Others...
        }
    } GUIObj = GUI();
}

// ...
```